# How to move the Vagrant environment?

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

> "vagrant init: ...a Vagrant environment by creating an initial
>   Vagrantfile..."

I moved **that folder** from E:/ to C:/ in windows, and I'm having this silly error when trying to do a `vagrant snapshot restore XXX`

```
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "7aff8d5d-7193-4f6d-966b-4076543c0e90", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: RawFile#0 failed to create the raw output file E:/Proyectos/do-sf2-dev/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

From I understand, **VirtualBox keeps referencing the E:/ drive.**

I tried manually editing any references from E:/ to C:/ I can find under **that folder**, and also in the VirtualBox GUI for the concerning machine but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is late but will hopefully help the next person to encounter this issue. The error is because the machine is configured to output to a location that doesn't exist anymore. When moving a Vagrant environment to another drive you'll need to update some Vagrant metadata in addition to moving the VM files. You can use `vagrant up --debug` to see exactly what the error is referring to.

If you move the .vagrant.d directory you'll need to set the environment variable `VAGRANT_HOME` to its new location. On windows you need to restart for this to take effect. If that doesn't work add one of the following to your vagrantfile:

- `v.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]`

  - This disables serial output to the missing log file (ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log)

or

- `v.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "file", File.join(Dir.pwd, "ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log") ]`

  - This updates the path of the log file to point to the current directory.

For most vagrant setups this should be enough , however, I also needed to re-create the path to the erring log file before `vagrant up` would work successfully. After that I ran `vagrant provision` and was able to delete the old file path without issues.

These posts were also helpful (References):

- https://medium.com/@cedricdue/moving-vagrant-boxes-and-related-virtualbox-vms-to-another-drive-f1d7c50d20bc
- https://superuser.com/questions/256192/how-to-move-virtualbox-files
- https://github.com/joelhandwell/ubuntu_vagrant_boxes/issues/1
- https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8275